# 16.04: Filezilla crashes when performing any remote action

Tags: 16.04, ftp, sftp, filezilla

Having some problems with Filezilla crashing/closing itself unexpectedly whenever I try to perform an action on a (sftp) remote server, whether that's changing directories, uploading, or downloading a file. It connects just fine, and I can navigate local directories with no problem, but when I try to do anything on any remote server the whole thing shuts down.

The version is Filezilla v3.21.0, compiled for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. The Filezilla log files aren't very enlightening:

```
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Status: Connecting to grantshop.ca...
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Command: open "grants@grantshop.ca" 22
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Command: Pass: ********
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Status: Connected to grantshop.ca
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Command: pwd
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Response: Current directory is: "/home/grants"
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Command: ls
2017-08-10 14:41:23 4088 1 Status: Listing directory /home/grants
2017-08-10 14:41:24 4088 1 Status: Directory listing of "/home/grants" successful
2017-08-10 14:42:40 4088 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/home/grants/grantshop.ca"...
```

Uploading/downloading produces similar logs, where the last log line is `7088 3 Status: Starting download of /home/grants/something.txt` or something similar.

Running Filezilla from the terminal gets me this:

```
Reading locale option from /home/user/.filezilla/filezilla.xml
03:36:32 PM: Debug: Failed to connect to session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
wxD-Bus: Signal from /org/freedesktop/DBus, member NameAcquired
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 2
wxD-Bus: Reply to RegisterClient, our object path is /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client27
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 3
wxD-Bus: Reply: Error: The name org.freedesktop.PowerManagement was not provided by any .service files
wxD-Bus: Falling back to org.gnome.SessionManager
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 4
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful, cookie is 1943892549
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting idle
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 5
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Request successful
wxD-Bus: CPowerManagementInhibitor: Requesting busy
filezilla: symbol lookup error: filezilla: undefined symbol: _ZN2fz18replace_substringsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEES7_S7_
```

Comment: This solved my problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000269/how-can-i-upgrade-filezilla-to-the-current-version ~Sparkandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post on the Filezilla forums](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=45830) says that last-line terminal error can be caused by libfilezilla being out of date, but I don't even have that lib. It is true that my installed version of FZ wasn't up to date, however. Since the package manager doesn't have the most recent version and the [official compiling/dependency instructions are gone](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_and_Getting_Dependencies_on_Linux), I downloaded the [Debian 8.0 version](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1).

A test run of the Debian version operated just fine, so I backed up /usr/bin/filezilla and replaced my existing bin and share files with the downloaded ones. Working like a charm now.

Comment: hi @Boxot debian 8.0 is going to https://prnt.sc/h30hmg version 3.28 but the file is given in tar.gz2

Comment: How did you do a test run of the Debian 8 version? And where does one find the existing bin & share files that the archive contains in order to replace them. I've searched all over my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation and it's all been to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Greg, for the test run I just downloaded and unpacked the tar to my desktop, and ran the program from there without integrating it into the system proper. Once I confirmed it worked, I copied the relevant files into the usr etc. directories.

For the bin and share files, I used /usr/bin/filezilla as mentioned; if that directory doesn't exist on your machine, try using the "locate filezilla" command in terminal.

Comment: @Raghu I figured as much, but I was hoping the program would update with the system instead of me having to download and unpack and install a tar. :\ Just an inconvenience is all.

Answer (score 5):

I had set up the "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" repo.  Then I installed Filezilla.  On 03/27/2018 that gave me Filezilla 3.21.  I was using sFTP.  It crashed every second and it never successfully transferred any files.  (I never tried old FTP.)

Anyway, I removed the "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" using the Ubuntu SW Center.  Then removed Filezilla.

```
sudo apt-get purge filezilla
sudo apt-get autoremove
rm -fr ~/.config/filezilla
```

Then I reinstalled filezilla from the default deb repo.

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

This gave me version 3.15.  It works fine so far.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Maybe 3.21 is just a buggy distro for Ubuntu users. Have you tried using the most recent 3.32 for Debian 9.0? Does it cooperate better?

Comment: I got rid of the problems with disconneting after an update to 3.33.