# How can I upgrade filezilla to the current version?

Tags: 16.04, ftp, filezilla

Filezilla was acting weird with version 3.21, which is pretty old; the current one is 3.30. So, I decided to update it but it looks like this is not possible. After spending hours trying it, I returned to the old version 3.21.

Is there any possible way to update it , or is there any other FTP client that works better (and can be updated)?

Update:

I run Ubuntu 16.04 TLS, the post about repositories not having latest versions is not relevant because I need procedures to follow, not an open discussion.

Comment: i have ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**NOTE:** The newest precompiled version of Filezilla is now 3.49.1 which was built for Debian 10.0 (Buster).  If you are running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or older, the libc6 library does not contain GLIBC 2.28 which is now required by the precompiled version of Filezilla 3.49.1.  Ubuntu 18.10 and newer contain the newer libc6 and are not affected by this.  I removed the section below that contained how to replace your installation with the precompiled version since it really is outdated now. It is recommended to install Filezilla from source or through the `apt-get install` method (which will be an older version).  It is probably best to remove any version that was installed with `apt` since it might try to "upgrade" back to the older version.

---

### Build and install Filezilla 3.49.1 from source:

Install the prerequisites for installing from source:

**Older than 20.04:**

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake wx-common libpugixml-dev libsqlite3-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev nettle-dev gnutls-bin libgnutls28-dev libunistring-dev
```

**For 20.04:**

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake wx-common libpugixml-dev libsqlite3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev nettle-dev gnutls-bin libgnutls28-dev libunistring-dev libdbus-1-dev libgtk-3-dev
```

You will need to update to libnettle 3.4.1:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/nettle/nettle-3.4.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf nettle-3.4.1.tar.gz
cd nettle-3.4.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Also need to update gnutls to version 3.6.13:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnutls/v3.6/gnutls-3.6.13.tar.xz
tar xvf gnutls-3.6.13.tar.xz
cd gnutls-3.6.13/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Download `pugixml` and build from source:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/zeux/pugixml/releases/download/v1.10/pugixml-1.10.tar.gz
tar zxvf pugixml-1.10.tar.gz
cd pugixml-1.10/
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Download `libfilezilla-0.23.0` that is needed from [here](https://lib.filezilla-project.org/download.php).  *NOTE: Only `libfilezilla-0.11.0` is available in the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repositories.  Also, only `libfilezilla-0.19.0` is available in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repositories.*

Copy the file to `/tmp` then extract, build and install:

```
cd /tmp
tar -xvjf libfilezilla-0.23.0.tar.bz2 
cd libfilezilla-0.23.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now get the source for Filezilla 3.49.1 from [here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1)

Copy the file to `/tmp`, then extract, build and install:

```
cd /tmp
tar -vxjf FileZilla_3.49.1_src.tar.bz2 
cd filezilla-3.49.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

With the lib installs you might get the following message if it doesn't start or FileZilla may not be starting at all:

> filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libfilezilla.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

To fix it, simply run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Now run FileZilla and it should be the newest version:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know there are lots of edits to this, I was fixing the bz2 extraction line.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i searched a lot and i could not do that by myself

Comment: Configuring libfilezilla-0.18.1 also requires Nettle if you don't already have it: `sudo apt install nettle-bin` or http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/nettle.html for the latest version. My system also only had GnuTLS 3.5.18 and this version requires GnuTLS 3.5.7 (which also requires nettle and gmplib).

Comment: @Boxbot Somehow I already had the two installed on both my systems that I do these tests on.  I have added them to the Pre-Reqs.  However, GnuTLS 3.5.18 is newer than 3.5.7 so there shouldn't be any issue with the build, or at least what I have built on different systems already.

Comment: Extracting a binary tarball and copying its contents into system directories? No. Just no. -1