# Cannot run FileZilla on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, filezilla, gnutls

Got this message today (Ubuntu 18.10) trying to run FileZilla 3.33.0.

```
  ****GnuTLS error -50 in gnutls_priority_set_direct: The request is invalid.
Error:  Failed to initialize TLS.
Error:  Could not connect to server****
```

and got [this response online](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?p=166813#p166813):

> Bug in Ubuntu, they have for some insane reason decided to switch to a
>   development version of GnuTLS just weeks prior to the Ubuntu 18.10
>   release. Contact Ubuntu support and have them switch back to a version
>   of GnuTLS that had been marked stable at the time of release of said
>   GnuTLS version.

Any idea how I can correct this problem?

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -e filezilla -e tls` and `which filezilla` to the question. I can't reproduce your issue on clean fully upgraded 18.10 VM. Where did you see the "response" about bug?

Comment: Actually, I see the same error message, just installed FileZilla for the first time. FileZilla is "3.33.0-1ubuntu1", libgnutls30 is "3.6.4-2ubuntu1.1", the OS is Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: The response in question is here: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=50308

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Ubuntu 18.10. The problem is observed for many different hosts. Installing an earlier version of gnutls didn't fix problem.

The solution is to install the latest version of Filezilla (e.g. FileZilla 3.40 instead of default 3.33 repo version).

You can't install the latest version from a deb package, because you'll get conflict with libhodweed4. But you can replace as like described here: [How can I upgrade filezilla to the current version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000269/how-can-i-upgrade-filezilla-to-the-current-version)