# upgrade filezilla to latest version

Tags: 18.04, ftp, filezilla

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I want to install filezilla to the latest version (3.45.1)

According to this thread: **[How can I upgrade filezilla to the current version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000269/how-can-i-upgrade-filezilla-to-the-current-version)**

i got stuck when ./configure

```
 configure: error: GnuTLS 3.5.7 or greater was not found. You can get it from https://gnutls.org/
```

but i have installed the gnutls

```
sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnutls-bin is already the newest version (3.5.18-1ubuntu1.1).
```

How can I fix this problem ???

Comment: You are trying to compile; so my guess from your error is you require the dev package (not binary).  See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnutls&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all  (possibly `libgnutls28-dev`)

Comment: @guiverc it seems that was the problem. Thx :) I have another problem...when run ./configure on filezilla-3.45.1 source code... `configure: error: libdbus not found. Install libdbus or configure with --without-dbus` and I am not sure what libdbus to install. libdbus-1-dev ????

Comment: You are compiling, so it'll be the [-]dev package.

Comment: problem solved! :-) Now I have the newest version of filezilla (3.45.1).  Thx again @guiverc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compile; so I believe from your error that you require the [-]dev (*development*) package, not the *binary* you have installed. The binary is for run-time only; you're trying to compile.

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnutls&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all , where I suspect `libgnutls28-dev` is what you need.

As to your next question in comments, again as you're compiling you need the [-]dev package